# How to know the url of ajax request at any website

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I use some website, is it possible to get the url of ajax requests, current page sends. By the help of browser or another tool.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Developer Tools or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will do the trick. [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is another good tool.

Comment: Also the Firefox "Tamper Data" add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Net tab of the browser's developer tools, or use a logging proxy like Charles.